# PrimeFaces panelGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any alternative for `panelGrid` in PrimeFaces components? I need something more fixable to design forms. Something which supports `colspan` attribute someway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is `colspan`, then just use plain vanilla HTML or use Tomahawk's [`<t:panelGrid>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_panelGrid.html) with [`<t:panelGroup>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_panelGroup.html) which supports the `colspan` attribute.

RichFaces has also components supporting `colspan`, but that doesn't always work flawlessly together with PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using "p:row and p:column" in panel Grid

example:

```
<p:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px">
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="7">1995-96 NBA Playoffs</p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="2">Conf. Semifinals</p:column>
        <p:column colspan="2">Conf. Finals</p:column>
        <p:column colspan="2">NBA Finals</p:column>
        <p:column>Champion</p:column>
    </p:row>

</f:facet>

<p:row>
    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">Seattle</p:column>
    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">4</p:column>

    <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">Seattle</p:column>
    <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">4</p:column>

    <p:column rowspan="5">Seattle</p:column>
    <p:column rowspan="5">2</p:column>

    <p:column rowspan="11" style="font-weight: bold;">Chicago</p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

[For Complete Example please visit prime faces show case](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no alternative for `<h:panelGrid>` yet.

But hopefully you can use the `<p:layout>` and `<p:layoutUnit>` to more fixable form design.

And there are no restrictions using `<table>` and `<div>` with little CSS. Personally I would stick to the panelGrid because it is a JSF component, with more JSF-ish attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why my previous answer was deleted by admins but PrimeFaces 3.1 will have a panelGrid component. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf

Comment: Your previous answer was deleted because it was not an answer, but more an invitation/discussion. Stack Overflow isn't exactly a discussion forum :) +1 for the new `<p:panelGrid>` though. The `<p:row>` is a very good idea.