# primefaces panelgrid colspan not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to set a panelgrid inside a dialog. Everything seems to be working except the colspan. I've check this post [PrimeFaces panelGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165292/primefaces-panelgrid) but its year and half old. From the primefaces manual and showcase, colspan should be accepted by datatable and panelGrid.

```
            <h:form id="idFormAddDialog">

            <p:panelGrid id="idPanelAddUsers" columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="dAddOutUser" value="Username:"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="dAddOutUser" value="#{userController.username}"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel for="dSelRole" value="Role:"></h:outputLabel>

                <h:selectOneMenu id="dSelRole" value="#{userController.role}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Researcher" itemValue="2"></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="3"></f:selectItem>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel for="dAddINPassword1" value="Password: "></h:outputLabel>
                <p:password id="dAddINPassword1" value="#{userController.password}" feedback="true"></p:password>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="2">
                        <p:separator></p:separator>
                        <!-- <p:separator></p:separator>-->
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:commandButton value="OK" actionListener="#{userController.addUser()}"  ></p:commandButton>
                <p:button value="Cancel"></p:button>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

But I'm not able to find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, if you want to use `p:row` and `p:column` in `p:panelGrid` remove `columns` attribute, and manage rows and column manually with `p:row` and `p:column` tags. Everything inside `p:panelGrid` must be inside `p:row` tags. Example:

```
<p:panelGrid id="idPanelAddUsers">
  <p:row>
    <p:column></p:column>
    <p:column></p:column>
    <p:column></p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
    <p:column colspan="2"></p:column>
    <p:column></p:column>
  </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I when now to colspan and rowspan specification in the manual "PanelGrid supports rowspan and colspan options as well, in this case row and column markup should be defined manually."

Once more thanks for the quick answer.